# Need to pass different environment variable values for each docker container while run docker image

Tags: java, docker, nginx, kubernetes, dockerfile

I am new to docker and i worked in one small scenario. Situation is, i need to pass different values during each docker container creation using docker run command.

```
FROM nginx:alpine
ARG files 
ENV files=$files
COPY $files /usr/share/nginx/html
```

For building docker image using `docker build . -t sample-ui` command.

while running the docker container, i am passing one html file like below.

```
docker run -p 8090:80 -e files=sample1.html sample-ui
```

Now i just checked in browser, http://localhost:8090/sample1.html and it works fine and i am able to see the sample1.html web page.

Now i am going to create another container on top of same docker image with different html page as environment value.

```
docker run -d -p 8091:80 -e files=sample2.html sample-ui
```

But now the second container also have sample1.html only but not sample2.html. Means http://localhost:8091/sample2.html is not working. http://localhost:8091/sample1.html is working.

Anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: The COPY step gets executed when you build the image not when you run the image.

Comment: @Pankaj-thanks for the reply. Still I have question like how COPY works perfectly during first container creation. But during Second container creation it not worked. If COPY command is not suitable, is there any other way to achieve this. do you have any idea?

Comment: My requirement is somehow I need to pass different values during each docker container creation. Please let me know if you got any ideas

Comment: The very likely hood is that the file exists in your image; you can debug it; I mean can check inside. so if you will just do this - "docker run -it sample-ui sh" you will be inside your container and then can check what exists at the path - /usr/share/nginx/html.

Comment: Your requirement seems to be anti-pattern to the concept of building images to bundle code + dependencies together;

Comment: @Pankaj,  forget this COPY command working.  is there any way to pass different environment values to each container while Creation using docker run command.

Answer (score 1):

From Dockerfile

```
COPY $files /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This `COPY` command will execute while building the docker image using the Dockerfile.

While I build docker image using above **Dockerfile** It copied all files and directory of my current folder into `/user/share/nginx/html` folder.
To ensure run following:

```
docker exec -it <container id> sh
/ # ls /user/share/nginx/html
```

> Now i just checked in browser, http://localhost:8090/sample1.html and it works fine and i am able to see the sample1.html web page.

So, In your case there might be `sample1.html` filed present while you are building image. That's why above url working.

`sample2.html` was not present, so it's not working

Comment: @Hoque-thanks, is there any way to pass different environment values to each container while Creation using docker run command. Forget this COPY command, I just need to pass different values

Answer (score 0):

Now I am successfully pass environmental variable values during docker container creation( docker run Image name).

docker run -d -p 8091:80 -e "files=sample2.html" sample-ui

Actually we need to give double quote as mentioned above.

By this way,  I am able to create different docker container with dynamic html files